# What is the right prototype of using $out for such requirement?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am new at MongoDb and I want to save the details of "sellings" that belong to "Tommy" in a new collection called "result1". The collection that I deal with is the following:

```
    "food seller" : {
        "seller" : "Tommy",
        "sellings" : [
            {
                "FOOD" : {
                    "food name" : "Rice"
                }
            },
            {
                "FOOD" : {
                    "food name" : "Noby",
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

I tried the followings, but no doubt, they were going to not work. Not properly!

```
db.collection.aggregate([ {$project:{"food seller.seller":"Tommy"}}, {$out:"result1"}]);

db.collection.aggregate([ {$project:{"Tommy":"$food seller.seller.sellings"}}, {$out:"result1"} ]);

db.collection.aggregate([ {$project:{"food seller.seller":"Tommy"}}, {$out:"result1"}]);
```

I know my problem is not getting the right prototype of doing such requirement. Meaning, those codes above are not dealing with the "sellings" array, they just dealing with the "seller".

To sum up, it is wanted to get the "sellings" array of "Tommy" to be in its won collection called "result1".

Comment: I think you should use a [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) stage first, to filter all the documents with "food seller" value as "Tommy".

Comment: If you remove the `$out` stage do you get the correct result set?

Comment: @Aki : Right now it's only for `Tommy` by any chance in future do you do the same thing for any other seller to same collection `result1` ?

Comment: No. I only want the sellings that belong to Tommy to be in its won collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$match:{"food seller.seller":"Tommy"}},{$project:{"food seller.sellings.FOOD":1}},{$out:"result"}]);
```

This code extracts the "sellings" array contents, that belong to "Tommy", to a new collection called "result". So, if you write `db.result.find({});` you will view that array alone. –

Comment: This code extracts the "sellings" array contents, that belong to "Tommy", to a new collection called "result". So, if you write ```` db.result.find({});```` you will view that array alone.

Comment: Aha, that’s really useful! Can you edit your answer to include that information?